# Hints in proving the irreducibility of the permutation representation of $S_n$

Tags: representation-theory, characters

Can anyone give me any hints of how to proceed: I have scoured this forum and exhausted all online notes.

I am trying to prove that there is no room for an irreducible permutation representation, $\rho_{\text{perm}}$.

**Attempt 1**
By dimensionality theorem,
$$
|G| = \sum_i \dim{V_i}^2
$$
I then ran into issues as thus,
$$
|S_n| = n! = \sum_i \dim{V_i}^2 =?\  V_{\text{ident}}^2 + V_{\text{alt}}^2 + V_{\text{perm}}^2 = 1^2 + 1^2 + n^2
$$
where $=?$ indicates my confusion since it appears as though there is room for the permutation representation in certain cases for large n and so it is not general.

**Attempt 2** I followed the examples I have worked out by using the trace or character of the representation, $\chi(\rho)$ such that, $||\chi(\rho)||^2 = 1$ iff irreducible. My further issue is then that whilst I can practically calculate this trace for a specific example I do not know how to compute for $S_n$ generally.

**Attempt 3** I then tried looking for invariant subspaces, I know that $\rho_{\text{perm}}$ acts on an n-dimensional subspace of orthogonal vectors but I can't see how I can then obtain a second invariant subspace. I have seen a few posts mentioning a conjugate subspace but I don't understand the theory of how this arises / can't find anything that sticks out online / my notes.

**Attempt 4** I know $\rho_{\text{perm}}$ decomposes into other representations and I thought of proving it decomposes into $\rho_{\text{alt}}$ and $\rho_{\text{indent}}$. However, I realised that this doesn't satisfy $S_2$ and furthermore I found notes suggesting this is not the only decomposition of $\rho_{\text{perm}}$ either.

Comment: I am aware this duplicates similar questions but I have looked thoroughly through these similar examples and as detailed - I am unable to apply them to my problem. Consequently, I am looking for hints. Let me know if this does not fall under the scope of the forum

Comment: What exactly are you trying to prove?

Comment: That the permutation representation is irreducible for all $S_n$, any hints would be highly welcome. I think the best approach is to decompose as in my 3rd/4th attempt but as above I encountered issues with that approach

Comment: What is "the permutation representation"?

Comment: A representation of $S_n$ that acts on a vector space of $n$ orthogonal vectors to permute them as I understand it. Please correct me if I am mistaken though.

Comment: See this MO thread (Qiaochu Yuan's answer, to be specific): http://mathoverflow.net/questions/17230/permutation-representation-inner-product

Comment: This is exactly at the right level and follows directly from my studies. Thank you I was not aware of math overflow.